# Type regular documents using regular characters in Latex?

Tags: characters

I am typing letters in Latex and I would like to just allow characters such as & and ' to be treated as regular characters and not latex related commands. Is there a simple way to this? Thanks

Comment: You could use a `verbatim` environment or insert them in a `listings` environment, or change the activeness of those characters.

Comment: How do I use the verbatim package?

Comment: `\begin{verbatim}  your text with & and ' characters \end{verbatim}` -- but it does not look very nice. You don't need an extra package.

Comment: Your right, vertbatim does not look very nice. How does listing work?

Comment: The question is, whether you want just put some (code) examples of `&` and `'` characters in running text or layout them nicely... or just use David's answer below ;-)

Comment: Could you clarify your requirement for `'`: it _is_ treated entirely as a 'normal' char.

Comment: Sorry I cannot remember what characters are treated as normal characters or not. It might be either ` or '

Comment: Well you will need *some* special character to end the document. But if you can do without, say, | in your document, then you could try `\catcode\`\|=\active
\def|{\end{document}}
\makeatletter
\@noligs
\let\do\@makeother \dospecials` and put `|` at the very end of your document :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
'
```

is treated as a regular character.

For

```
&
```

if you don't need any tables or math alignments just put

```
\catcode`\&=12
```

after `\begin{document}`

You should probably use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

as well, as the default OT1 encoding is a little eccentric